# OnResume() and OnSleep() called but not working properly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm a new Xamarin developper and I'm trying to build an app with Xamarin.Forms. Everything works properly on the app but I noticed a strange behaviour : be it on device or with the emulator, when I turn the power off one time then on again, OnSleep() and OnResume() methods work just fine.

But the problem is, when I repeat the same operation a second time, the application freezes and to unlock it I have to either close the app and open it again or go to menu where you can select other apps working in background (I don't know how it's called) and return on the app. I checked with breakpoints and those two methods are called on the first and second time. I tried removing everything from those methods but the problem persists. Does anyone know why it behaves like that ? Thank you.

In my App.xaml.cs :

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        if (isLoggedIn())
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MDPage());
            GeneralViewModel general = new GeneralViewModel();
            general.checkUser();
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        if (isLoggedIn()) //With a breakpoint, this is executed
        {

            MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MDPage()); 
            /*this is also executed but the second time, 
             *even if it is executed the application freezes*/

            GeneralViewModel general = new GeneralViewModel();
            general.checkUser();

        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }
    }

    public bool isLoggedIn()
    {
        if (Settings.GeneralSettings != null && Settings.GeneralSettings != "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The GeneralViewModel method I call (btw even without it the problem persists)

```
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => checkUser());
    }
    public Task checkUser()
    {
        if (Settings.GeneralSettings != null && Settings.GeneralSettings != "")
        {

            DoSomething();

        }
        else
        {

                try
                {
                    var data = Application.Current.MainPage;

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await data.DisplayAlert("Information(s)", "Vous avez été déconnecté", "OK");
                    });

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exception");

                }

        }
        return default;


    }
```

edit : I checked the console and it seems even though nothing appears on the screen, when I press a button on my frozen page the action the button should do happens but the screen doesn't change.

Comment: Post some code where the issue is

Comment: Post some additional code. Also, try creating a brand new project and see if it happens with that project. If not, compare the 2 projects and start ruling out differences.

Comment: I edited my post and I have question : is it possible for a nugget to cause this problem ?

Comment: I'm not able to re-create your issue with these code. Just from code, looks like you're creating infinite loops with Settings.GeneralSettings != null && Settings.GeneralSettings != "", when DoSomething() call checkUser() and checkUser() call DoSomething().

Comment: I know it's an infinite loop, but as I said even without this the screen freezes the second time I enter the app after turning the power off.

Comment: Then, since your code above is not runnable, I suggest you could provide a minimal runnable sample code that can reproduce the issue to others for locating the problem. Also, whether it is caused by a nugget, it also needs check. If your code is not sharable, you can create a new project and add things step by step to see what's creating your problem.

Comment: I'm comming back here with some news : I've tried some things on my own and I have some news.
It seems that the problem doesn't come from my code because I did the same thing with a brand new project, without any NuGet (just the MainPage as a navigation page and an other page). 
The problem still occurs on this new project (just a reminder for the problem : when I press the power button then I press it a second time to show the screen, everything works but if I do the same thing a second time, the screen freezes).
And also, it doesn't come from onSleep or onResume since I didn't use them

Comment: @Axel Mola I managed to reproduce the issue on emulator with Pie 9.0 - API 28, and when I create an Android local project with java the issue persists. When I use another emulator with Nougat - API 25 or Q - API 29, the issue disappears both in Xamarin and Android local projects. But I can't reproduce the issue on a device, maybe it's due to different OS version, do you mind share your device info about OS version and API level with me?

Comment: Sure @NicoleLu my emulator uses pie 9.0 and API 28. I tried my app on my device aswell and now that I updated it to android 10 the problem doesn't occur anymore.